# Is there a quantum number associated with linear momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, atomic-physics, observables

Energy and angular momentum have a quantum number associated with them:

$$ E\rightarrow n $$

$$ |\vec{L}|\rightarrow l $$

$$ L_z\rightarrow m_l $$

Is there also a quantum number associated with linear momentum? I don't think so, but why not?

$$ p\rightarrow ?$$

Comment: The first three operators all commute with the Hamiltonian (which is not the case for the momentum operator) and therefore can be known precisely at the same time as the energy. The quantum number classifies an eigenstate: $\widehat H\psi_n=E_n\psi_n$, $\widehat L^2\psi_l=l(l+1)\hbar^2\psi_l$ or $\widehat  L_z\psi_{m_l}=m_l\hbar\psi_{m_l}$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. What happens when you do the momentum operator?

Comment: You're welcome! If you take $H=\frac{\widehat p^2}{2m}+V(x)$ like you do for the hydrogen problem, then you get $[H,p]=\nabla V(x)$, so it won't vanish. See for example here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest-Theorem#Orts-_und_Impulsoperatoren

Comment: So in short there is no quantum number for linear momentum in a hydrogen atom, because that would be continuous (the gradient of the potential). In that sense linear momentum acts still 'classically' if I understand correctly. Linear momentum is not 'quantized'.

Comment: Quantum linear momentum is a good quantum number for a free system, although its spectrum is continuous, not discrete, but, naturally, it is *not* a good quantum number for the Hydrogen atom, or a system with a nontrivial potential which localizes it. Are you asking about periodic systems?